# Which way is better (matching Onion Architecture in MVC pattern) for using Provider?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, linq, mvc, entity-framework

In onion arch. we have multi layer structre:

UI (User interface).
BL (Business Logic / Services).
RE (Repositories).

UI uses BL to get data from RE with some conditions, my question is which is better approach (as standard) to get data from BL:

In Repository (Data Access Layer):

```
public class PersonRepository
{
   PersonEFDbContext context = new PersonEFDbContext();
   public IEnumerable<Person> GetPerson(Expression<Func<Person,bool>> Where)
   {
      return context.PersonsList.Where(Where).ToList();
   }
}
```

Entity:

```
public class Person
{
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int NationalityId { get; set; }
}
```

case 1:

```
public class PersonProvider
{
    private PersonRepository repository { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonListByNationality(int NationalityId)
    {
       return repository.GetPerson(p => p.NationalityId == NationalityId);
    }
}
```

then I have to use it in UI like this way:

```
public class PersonListViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<Person> PersonsList { get; set; }
   public PersonListViewModel(PersonProvider Provider, int NationalityId)
   {
      PersonsList = Provider.GetPersonListByNationality(NationalityId);
   }       
}
```

case 2:

```
public class PersonProvider
{
    private PersonRepository repository { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Person> GetPersonList(Expression<Func<Person,bool>> Where)
    {
       return repository.GetPerson(Where);
    }
}
```

then I have to use it in UI like this way:

```
public class PersonListViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<Person> PersonsList { get; set; }
   public PersonListViewModel(PersonProvider Provider, int NationalityId)
   {
      PersonsList = Provider.GetPersonList(p=>p.NationalityId == NationalityId);
   }       
}
```

So where is the right place to set conditions, which one is better for later maintenance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> public class PersonRepository
> {
>     PersonEFDbContext context = new PersonEFDbContext();
>     public IEnumerable<Person> GetPerson(Expression<Func<Person,bool>> Where)
>     {
>        return context.PersonsList.Where(Where).ToList();
>     }
> }
> ```

Let us first talk about this little code snipet.

Usually I would say that it is always best to code against interfaces so returning an `IEnumerable<T>` would be the way to go **but** because we are dealing with database access a consumer of this method would assume hey, it is an `IEnumerable<T>` so if I access this there will be several trips to the db. The consumer doesn't know that you had called `ToList()` before you returned it so the consumer will just call `ToList()` on the result so he is on the safe side.

This additional call to `ToList()` doesn't come at no cost. It involves some null checks, casts, initialization of objects, and some copy work.

I would like to suggest to return an `IList<Person>` instead which makes it clear for the caller that it is a list.

If we now look at the method I like to mention 2 points.

- based on the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) method parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing, so `Where` should be `where`.
- a method parameter named `Where` isn't well named. A much better name would be e.g `filterExpression` or `filterCondition`.

That beeing said, let me answer (although it is my personal opinion) you question about which of the version is better/should be used.

There are two sides

- if you use the second approach you are limiting any caller to use `NET 3.5` and higher.
- if you use the first approach you are limiting the caller in the meaning of flexibility.

Personally I  would go with the second approach because of the increased flexibility it will bring in the game.

Small nitpicking aside from the mentioned points:

Let your variables and operators some space to breathe. Here

> ```
> public class PersonListViewModel
> {
>    IEnumerable<Person> PersonsList { get; set; }
>    public PersonListViewModel(PersonProvider Provider, int NationalityId)
>    {
>       PersonsList = Provider.GetPersonList(p=>p.NationalityId == NationalityId);
>    }       
> }
> ```

this would be more readable if you add a space after `p` and after `=>` like so

```
public class PersonListViewModel
{
   IEnumerable<Person> PersonsList { get; set; }
   public PersonListViewModel(PersonProvider Provider, int NationalityId)
   {
      PersonsList = Provider.GetPersonList(p => p.NationalityId == NationalityId);
   }       
}
```

Comment: Flexibility is good everywhere, and I agree to have it, my point is the list which comes from business logic should not be different, so we don't have to allow any body to change the conditions, and to use different conditions in many places.

thanks for the other remarks.

Comment: What exactly about the second approach limits it to 3.5+?

Comment: @RubberDuck `Expression` had first been introduce in NET 3.5